# MySQL Client taking more than 14 sec to be connected

Tags: networking, mysql, datacenter, database-administration, mysql8

IN our on-prem server we have installed mysql 4 node cluster 2 for mgmt and 2 for datanode. All are physical server with 1TB ram and 64 core processor. When a user trying to connect to mysql server from application VM its taking more than 14 second. But in my case while connection to that server from my computer its taking less than a second. For application VMs we provide we give them a IP range. IS ip range are the problem ? Because after connection being established its taking less than a second to fetch or get response from db server. But for each new connection its taking 14 second and this issue is while connecting from application VM. Is it a problem in networking or MySQL server ? Because while I ping db server from that server the avrg is 1.3 ms.

Comment: how does the user connect and how you connect exactly? moreover I would suggest that you take a look at [dba.se] due they are Db specialized

Comment: users connect from application vm. Initially due to the slowness of application we tried to connect db using "mysql -h x.x.x.x -u xxxx -p xxxx" command. Its taking more than 14 second to connect to db server. I never found that its taking less than 14sec. Either 14.xx second. From my physical computer its taking 0.04 S to connect to that db server.

Comment: That does not address the issue, nor the question asked. Are you providing an ip address or a host_name? What is the network infrastructure between the 2 types of client? You described a "ip range" for the problem cases - implying that these are NOT using the mysql cli client to connect. What are these using to connect? How are they configured?

Comment: Disable reverse DNS lookup by adding 

skip-name-resolve

inside my.cnf

Comment: using ip address. And as I said our db server has 4 node 2 for management and 2 for data and we are using ndb cluster. We are providing IP address to the client to connect. If client is connecting from a application vm then connection is taking more than 14 second and if im connecting to that server from my computer its taking 0.04ms. This is our on-prem servers and all of infra is managed by us.

Comment: You need to do some more troubleshooting, take a tcpdump for example and analyze that Wireshark if you see any issues on the network. Enable verbose logging and so on. Just basic troubleshooting.

Comment: Sounds like a reverse lookup or DNS problem.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to reduce connect delay.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.